# Vba macro subscript out of range

Tags: vba

Can't seem to figure out why I'm getting a run time error on the second line. Help please

```
Dim wb As Workbook 
Set wb = Workbooks(PLC)
wb.Close SaveChanges:False
Application.DisplayAlerts=True
End sub
```

Comment: What is in the variable `PLC`? Or perhaps you didn't mean to put a variable in there and instead meant to put the string literal "PLC" like `Set wb = Workbooks("PLC")`.

Comment: Doesn't matter still get same error with "

Comment: Then you do not have an open workbook with that name

Comment: What it's saying is that it can't find a workbook by that name (Either the literal name "PLC" or whatever is stored in variable `PLC`). If the workbook you want to put in that `wb` variable isn't currently open then you can do something like `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\your\workbook\PLC.xlsx")` and it will open it and assign it to the `wb` variable for you.

Comment: That is still not working it opens the excel book an puts it into my excel book but then the error comes up

Answer (score 0):

give this a shot
Sub test()

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("PLC.xlsx")
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you wish to open a workbook you should use the Workbooks.Open method. Workbooks(index) only applies to workbooks that are already opened. You can check if a workbook is already open by doing e.g.

```
Dim wb as workbook, isOpen as boolean, myName as string

myName = "PLC"
bIsOpen = false
For each wb in Workbooks 
    If wb.Name = myName Then
        bIsOpen = true
    End if
Next wb
```

And use the result in your next step.